# Convert 19-digit string to a number accurately in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large data file with columns of numbers delimited by blank spaces.  I would like to read them in as a numpy array.

I used `numpy.loadtxt(filename)` to read in the file.  The problem came when the code is trying to convert this 19-digit string to a number; it seems that it can only represent the first 17 digits accurately.

Here is a simplified example:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import numpy as np 

#use this s string to mimick the input txt file
s = StringIO('1237657220412736271 39843.3948')
arr = np.loadtxt(s)
print int(arr[0])
```

If you run it, you get

```
1237657220412736256
```

I know that it is possible to specify the type of data you have from `np.loadtxt()`, but even though I specified it to read it the first number as long integer, it still cannot represent the 19-digit string of number accurately.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Where did you specify the data type for `loadtxt()`? I don't see it in your posted code.

Comment: Why are you using numpy for this?

Comment: Do you just need to use `float64` or `float128` instead of the default, or do you actually need to handle arbitrary-precision decimals?

Comment: @Hewgill: I probably didn't in this posted code. Sorry but I did that when I test np.loadtxt.

Comment: @FogleBird: It was someone else's code so I tried to follow the the code's format.

Answer (score 2):

> even though I specified it to read it the first number as long integer

Well, given that your second value is a float, I'm not sure how you did that with a single type. But take that away, and you *can* read the first number as a longer integer type, and everything works fine:

```
>>> s = cStringIO.StringIO('1237657220412736271 39843')
>>> arr = np.loadtxt(s, dtype='i8')
>>> int(arr[0])
1237657220412736271
```

And likewise, if you specify a heterogeneous format like `('i8', 'f8')` and feed in your original string, that works fine with the original string.

So, my suspicion is that you didn't do what you think you did, and that's why it didn't work.

Another possibility is that by "long integer" you literally meant "a C long", and you're on a 32-bit platform or 64-bit Windows, where that means a 32-bit number. But I'm pretty sure `numpy` took that type away long again—and, if they didn't, it would give you a different problem than the one you're seeing.

Comment: If you just specify `i8` then you still need to convert the second column into float.

Comment: @tiago: Did you not read the text, or the code, beyond that one line? I explained that you have to take the float away to use `'i8'`, and showed that it works in that case, and then I explained how to specify a heterogeneous format immediately after that.

Comment: from your answer one would be tempted to do `dtype=('i8', 'f8')`, which doesn't work.

Comment: @tiago: Then one would get a `ValueError` immediately, and either go read the docs, or ask here how to do it. I'm not trying to write his code for him.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `np.loadtxt`, it is assuming all elements on the file are floats. This causes a precision problem when you convert it back to integer. You can specify a structured array read in `np.loadtxt`, which will enable it to read different columns with different data types:

```
arr = np.loadtxt(s, dtype={'names': ('ints', 'floats'),
                                     'formats': ('i8', 'f8')})
```

The difference here is that you get a structured array instead of a 2D array of a given datatype. You have to index it differently (either by name or index number), but you can check that the ints are read correctly:

```
>>> int(arr[0][0])
1237657220412736271
>>> int(arr['ints'][0])
1237657220412736271
```

(Note that this syntax will fail with your specific string `s` because it only has one line and will give a 0-d array, but it works with files of more than one line.)

Another alternative is to do two loads of `np.loadtxt`, one for each column:

```
arr1 = np.loadtxt(s, dtype='i8', usecols=(0,))
arr2 = np.loadtxt(s, dtype='f8', usecols=(1,))
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
>>> s = '1237657220412736271 39843.3948'
>>> a = s.split()
>>> int(a[0])
1237657220412736271
```

Unfortunately when numpy reads the 19-digit number as a floating point number, there is not enough precision to get all the significant digits, so there is a rounding error.  If you know the number is always going to fit in an `int` but is too large to be represented exactly in a double, you'll probably want need to do something like what I did above to work around that limitation.

Comment: And do what? Store it as an int plus a float? That would be hard to work with.

Comment: @abarnert Just depends on the application.  The OP was casting to int, so I assumed that they wanted an int representation.

Comment: The point is, `numpy` is loading this as a float64, and losing precision; the fact that he has an infinite-precision `int` copy of the same data outside of `numpy` doesn't seem all that useful.